# Multivalue Property Refiners rendering as semi-colon separated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, multiple-values, refiner

I'm having a hard time trying to get SharePoint to correctly display search refiners for Multivalued properties of a BCS model. I'm running SharePoint 2010 (not FAST) crawling content from a custom written search provider I wrote via a Visual Studio Business Connectivity project.

I'm crawling "records", each of which can be related to one or more Clients. "Clients" is a multi-valued property of type `List<System.String>`. SharePoint seems to be crawling the property and values just fine, but when I use this property as a refiner, it is displaying all the combinations of clients on instead of single distinct list of clients.

For example, it is returning;

- Client A
- Client A; Client C
- Client B; Client A
- Client C

I would like it to return;

- Client A
- Client B
- Client C

I've been looking around the web, and it looks though most of the articles and blogs re: this are written for SharePoint FAST Search or speak of making changes to config files on the SharePoint server. This seems to be pretty extreme for something that one would hope would be a fairly standard feature for SharePoint 2010.

If anyone could share the way to configure this correctly that would be must appreciated. I'm I doing something incorrect here? Should I be approaching this another way?

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no out of the box solution for this.

But with this solution and adjusted refiners you can get what you want: http://sprefiner.codeplex.com/